# Sorting an array of strings through the substring of each element C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

So, let's say I have an array of strings

```
    string[] stringArray = new string[5] { "3 Three", "8 Eight", "6 Six", "13 Thirteen", "24 Twenty Four";
```

I want to select the first numbers within each string element and sort this array in ascending order'
I want the outcome to be when using:

```
    Console.Writeline(String.Format("{0}, {1} and {2} are the lowest elements", stringArray[0], stringArray[1], stringArray[2]))
```

Displaying: 
'3 Three, 6 Six and 8 Eight are the lowest elements'

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.Split` and `int.Parse` with LINQ:

```
stringArray = stringArray.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split()[0])).ToArray();
```

another more efficient but less readable way is [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Array.Sort(stringArray, (s1, s2) => int.Parse(s1.Split()[0]).CompareTo(int.Parse(s2.Split()[0])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```
  string[] stringArray = new string[5] { "3 Three", "8 Eight", "6 Six", "13 Thirteen", "24 Twenty Four" };
  var ordered = stringArray.Select(s => new { number = int.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0]), text = s.Split(' ')[1] }).OrderBy(i => i.number).Select(arg => arg.number + " " + arg.text).ToArray();
  Console.WriteLine($"{ordered[0]}, {ordered[1]} and {ordered[2]} are the lowest elements");
```

Or in your simple scenario :

```
var ordered = stringArray.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0])).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"{ordered[0]}, {ordered[1]} and {ordered[2]} are the lowest elements");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] stringArray = new string[5] { "3 Three", "8 Eight", "6 Six", "13 Thirteen", "24 Twenty Four"};
string[] orderedArray = stringArray.OrderBy(ele => Convert.ToInt32(ele.Split(' ')[0])).ToArray();

Console.Writeline(String.Format("{0}, {1} and {2} are the lowest elements", orderedArray[0], orderedArray[1], orderedArray[2]))
```

Use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting or parsing the strings, it is a bit more efficient to just sort by the index of the first space and then by the string:

```
string[] stringArray = { "3 Three", "8 Eight", "6 Six", "13 Thirteen", "24 Twenty Four" };

var ordered = stringArray.OrderBy(s => s.IndexOf(' ')).ThenBy(s => s).ToArray();

Debug.Print(string.Join(", ", ordered)); // "3 Three, 6 Six, 8 Eight, 13 Thirteen, 24 Twenty Four"
```